# Understanding pointers in sample program

Tags: c++

I am having issues understanding pointers in C++. I thought I understood, but after this practice, it seems to be a challenge.

```
int main() {
        int x, y, z;
        int *p =&x, *q = &y, *r =&z;
        *p = 7;
        *q=4;
        *r = (x+y) * 4;
        *p=*q;
        x = (*q) + (*r);
        p=q;
        q=r;
        *r=*p;
        y = (*r * 3) +y;
        cout<<x << " " << y << " " << z<<endl;
        cout<< *p<<" " << *q << " " << *r<< endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

My thought process:
p and x = 7, q and y = 4. and r and z = 44.
Then p = q so x = 4. Then we change x to 48. Now when p=q and q=r, I am not sure what happens. Can anyone assist me to understand? Thank you

Comment: `p and x = 7` - to be more accurate, x equals 7, p equals the address of x, and by dereferencing p we can read out the value of x or change it. Same for the rest.

Comment: Keep clear in your mind the distinction between the expressions `p` and `*p`.   `p` is a clue you can use to find an `int` that is somewhere else in memory.  `*p` designates the memory location where the int is actually stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     +-----+
p -> |  x  |
     +-----+
     +-----+
q -> |  y  |
     +-----+
     +-----+
r -> |  z  |
     +-----+

p = q

     +-----+
     |  x  |
p    +-----+
 \   
  \  +-----+
   ->|     |
   ->|  y  |
  /  |     |
 /   +-----+
q
     +-----+
r -> |  z  |
     +-----+

q = r     

     +-----+
p    |  x  |
 \   +-----+
  \  +-----+
   ->|     |
     |  y  |
     +-----+
q
 \
  \  +-----+
   ->|     |
   ->|  z  |
  /  |     |
 /   +-----+
r
```

Comment: This one is the best answer to me

Comment: @Tay2510 glad that I could help!

Answer (score 3):

`p=q` assigns to `p` pointer the value of `q` pointer which is the address of `y`, so after this assignment `p` actually points to `y`.

The other part is similar.